# How to see the file created in a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a python script which generates outputs in a text file.I have built a docker image to run the script.While running the image its completing successfully but I cant see the output text file.

My Docker file is

```
From python:2.7
LABEL maintainer="ABC"
LABEL description="This Dockerfile creates MTA image"
WORKDIR /Temp
ADD script_v1.py connect.txt /Temp/
RUN pip install pexpect
CMD [ "python", "/Temp/script_v1.py" ]
```

In script_v1 script i have mentioned the /Temp location to generate he output

```
    sys.stdout=open("/Temp/EXPORT_OP.txt","w")
```

I am running the image from windows docker host in Linux container mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see at least two simple ways of achieving what you want:

1. Use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). In short, you'll make a directory in your host filesystem available to the container, and you'll use its path to save the file. The output will be available in that folder.
2. Use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) after the container exits to copy the file from a location inside the container into your host filesystem.

Another way, which will not make the file available directly on your host filesystem, will be to `docker exec -it <container> bash`, which will leave you with an open terminal inside the container, which you can use to `cd` into the correct directory and `cat` the file.

Answer (score 0):

As [Yury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4378400/yury-fedorov) as suggested, another way is to try using `volumes`. Start your container with a volume mapping a folder on the host to a folder in the container as shown below

```
docker run -d --name container_name -v /path/on/your/host:/path/in/your/container
```

This way, any changes in those two paths will be available to both the host and the container. You can also alter your container's start command `CMD` as shown below.

```
CMD python /Temp/script_v1.py && tail -f /path/to/your/file
```

This will allow you to see changes done to the file by using the `docker logs` command as shown below

```
docker logs -f container_name
```

I hope you find this helpful