# Docker git push before container is destroyed

Tags: node.js, git, docker

I have dockerized a Node project. This project generates files.

Whenever the container is destroyed I am losing all the files that are generated. I am thinking of using "SIGTERM" event and do a git push when the container is about to be destroyed.

Is there any other approach that could be used in this situation?

Comment: could add a bind mount to the local filesystem, then you push at your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`bind mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120411/4378400)). It allows to access your host filesystem from the container, meaning that the container is able to store the files in a directory available to the host even when it exits.

For your case it means that the project will generate files in some folder using file path local to the container, while you will still see the changes from the outside using your host system paths.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to be able to save the files inside your container before its destruction. You have several possibilities:

- [mount a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) on your container - your data will still be available even after container is destroyed, and can be mounted on a new container or backed-up somewhere else
- [use a bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) as pointed out by [Yury's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275890/5465973) - your data will be available on the host machine after container destruction
- use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) before destruction to backup your data on host machine

Answer (score 1):

In our CI framework we use Jenkins and Docker. Jenkins starts a Docker container and then runs a command in the container to build some software. When the software build is done the build script inside the container issues a command which commits and archives the container as an image to the Docker registry. The image contains all the temporary files and tool configuration. This allows us to recreate an container from an archived image later and re-run tests with all dependencies and generated files already in place.

The following script can be ran from inside a container:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex
# The docker registry should be located at a hostname:port address. (see push ref link below)
REGISTRY=TESTRACK:5000
TAG=${2}
CONTAINER_NAME=${1}

function get-container-id() {
    # When executed from within a docker container, the kernel cgroup file contains a control group for docker processes
    # The container id of the current container (from within that container) can be fetched this way.
    cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep "cpuset:/docker" | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\):cpuset:\/docker\///g'
    # Below, using head, is less reliable; the docker line is not always the first line in the cgroup
    # head -1 /proc/self/cgroup | cut -d/ -f3
}
CONTAINER_ID=$(get-container-id)
if [ -z ${CONTAINER_ID} ]; then
    echo "Error. Did not find a docker container value!"
    exit 1
fi
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#examples

docker commit ${CONTAINER_ID} ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER_NAME}:$TAG
docker tag ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER_NAME}:$TAG ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER_NAME}:latest

#remove existing images without tags
OLD=`docker images -f "reference=TESTRACK-1:5000/$CONTAINER_NAME" -f "dangling=true" -q`

if [ -n "${OLD}" ]; then
    docker rmi -f ${OLD} || true
fi


# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/
#do not show push progress
docker push ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER_NAME}:$TAG &> push_result_tag.txt
docker push ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER_NAME}:latest &> push_result.txt
```

Note that you can only run this script inside a container if that container has access to the Docker daemon. So you so should start a container with access to the docker daemon socket

```
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```